# Colliding a player and a maze wall

Tags: java, 2d

I am making a game very similar to [Tank Trouble](http://www.tanktrouble.com/). I cannot get t the tank to collide with the maze in the map.

Let `tx` and `ty` = the tank x and y value.
Let `x` and `y` = the walls x and y value.
Let `h` and `w` = the walls height and width.

```
public boolean collidesWith(double tx, double ty)
{
    if ((tx - 55 > x) && (tx + 55 < x + w) && (ty - 55 > y) && (ty + 55 < y + h))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: your code checks if the tank is completely contained inside the wall.  Is that what you want? Also, it's confusing that tx,ty are the center of the tank, but x,y is the top-left corner of the wall. Use center for both or topleft for both.

Comment: This is a debugging question. What do you *think* is the problem? Have you tried solving it? Do you know what the debugger is and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just return false whenever you find a case that makes it impossible for the two to intersect.

```
public boolean collidesWith(double tx, double ty) {
    if ((tx + 55 < x) || (tx - 55 > x + w) ||
        (ty + 55 < y) || (ty + 55 > y + h)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: this will always return true unless the wall is contained entirely inside the tank

Comment: You're right. At first I had only noticed the &&s and assumed that was the problem. Updated answer.

Comment: I think this new version is correct :)